# How to send filled pdf form to a url address and get field data?

Tags: python, flask, pdf-form

I have a pdf form prepared with Scribus. It has two fields "name" and "telephone" and a submit button for trying. I uploaded pdf to local server using Flask and showed on the web browser, but when I filled the form and click submit button nothing happens(form does not go to url that I gave while preparing the pdf form). I tried this with Okular and Document Viewer, but nothing happens again.

How can I send filled data to an address and access field values within python
code?

Comment: What is the pdf viewer? The pdf viewer must support this.

Comment: I tried with Okular and Document Viewer on Debian 6, but the main thing I want to do is sending this field data when pressed submit button on web browser. Then I should be able to process it within Flask app.

Comment: I don't think either of those are capable of submitting HTTP forms. Install Adobe Reader and see if that works.

Comment: Adobe Reader worked. Thank you.